# Pegar conteúdo de um captcha ou preencher form de site externo

Tags: php, ajax, libcurl

Bom dia pessoal do stackoverflow.
Eu estou passando por um problema que não vejo luz para solução.
Eu estou com a seguinte situação: 
Eu estou mexendo em um portal, e esse portal, precisava mandar informações para o site na nossa matriz. Então, ele faz um select, nesse select, é enviado via cURL para o form do outro site, até ai perfeito, só que esse site tem um captcha que está me travando há alguns dias.

Então, a minha diretora falou aqui, que não precisa enviar o form, pode apenas preenche-lo. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer algo do tipo, de preencher um form externo com as informações que precisa, até antes era minha ideia original.

Por exemplo pegar o id e preencher o valor.

```
$("#User_institution").val(valorQualquer) //no success do ajax.
```

Se não for possível fazer assim, quero saber se é possível pegar o captcha gerado quando envio o POST no cURL e enviar, como se fosse alguém preenchendo o captcha.

Att

**Requisição para a página que carrega os dados e recuperando o json**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        msg = data;
        var values = $.parseJSON(msg);
        nomeEmpresa = values[0].razao_social;
        emailEmpresa = values[0].email_comercial;
        telefone = values[0].tel_comercial;
        site = values[0].siteweb;
        rua = values[0].end_logradouro;
        numero = values[0].end_numero;
        bairro = values[0].end_bairro;
        estado = values[0].end_eatado;
        cidade = values[0].end_cidade;
        cep = values[0].end_cep;
        nomeResponsavel = values[0].nome;
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    },
    complete: function() {
        sendRequest(nomeEmpresa,emailEmpresa,telefone,site,rua,numero,bairro,cidade,cep,nomeResponsavel);
    }
});
```

**Recuperando as informações e transformando em json**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$Partner = new Partner();
$Cliques = new clicks();


date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$dataRegistro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$Cliques->setDataRegistro($dataRegistro);
$Cliques->setIdPartner($id);

$Partner->updateContCliques($id);


echo json_encode($Partner->listaParceiro($id));


$Cliques->inserir();

}
```

**Informações a serem enviadas**

```
function sendRequest(nomeEmpresa,emailEmpresa,telefone,site,rua,numero,bairro,cidade,cep,nomeResponsavel) {



        var myUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://ecoprintq.com/index.php/partnerApplication/create");
        var dados = "User_full_name:"+nomeResponsavel+"&User_institution:"+nomeEmpresa+"&User_email:"+emailEmpresa+"&PartnerApplication_phone:"+telefone+"&PartnerApplication_company_website:"+site+"&PartnerApplication_support_phone:"+telefone+"&PartnerApplication_support_email:"+emailEmpresa;
        $.ajax({
            url: "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl,
            data:dados,
            crossDomain:true,
            type: "GET",
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "text", // "xml", "json"

            success: function(data) {

                window.location.href = "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl + "&" + dados;

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });


    }
```

**Pegando o post do ajax e mandando para o form**

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['url']) || preg_match('#^(http|https)://[a-z0-9]#i', $_GET['url']) === 0) {
    echo 'URL inválida';
    exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

//pega o POST enviado via Ajax
$post = http_build_query($_POST);

//Envia o $post usando CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if($data === false)
{
    http_response_code(500);
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} elseif ($httpcode !== 200) {
    http_response_code($httpcode);

} else {
    echo $data;
}
```

Isso que eu tenho agora

Comment: Para complementar, é possível "agarrares" a imagem do captha... Mas não o seu valor via um programa

Comment: Algoritmos de quebra de `captcha` são muito específicos porque dependem do sistema que gera as imagens. Pra vc ter uma ideia, já tentaram fazer isso [aqui](https://github.com/hc0d3r/Consulta-cpf-cnpj) decifrando o áudio, mas parece que não funciona mais. Outra solução é usar `OCR` [vide 'tesseract'](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) e veja se vale o esforço.